# How do I align inference lines for sequents

Tags: tables

How do I adjust the inference lines so that they align?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }  
    \AxiomC{}
    \LeftLabel{Axiom: \ \ }
    \UnaryInfC{A \vdash A} \DisplayProof & \AxiomC{$\Gamma\vdash\Delta,A$}
    \AxiomC{$A, \Sigma\vdash\Pi$}
    \LeftLabel{Cut:}
    \BinaryInfC{$\Gamma,\Sigma\vdash\Delta,\Pi$}\DisplayProof \\[15pt]  
\end{tabular}   


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the reference point of a `bussproof` is somewhere almost random.

Comment: It works fine if one has \AxiomC{something} instead of \AxiomC{}.

Comment: You can also add `\strut` to all the printed math, as a reference height

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't understand. May you write it up as an answer?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks! I figured out how to use your \strut. :)

Comment: just so I understand, you want horizontal lines to be aligned, as opposed to some vertical symbols

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Precisely. You should write it up, for others to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added a `\strut` to any and everything that looked like it might typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }  
    \AxiomC{\strut}
    \LeftLabel{Axiom: \ \ \strut}
    \UnaryInfC{$A \vdash A$\strut} \DisplayProof & \AxiomC{$\Gamma\vdash\Delta,A\strut$}
    \AxiomC{$A, \Sigma\vdash\Pi\strut$}
    \LeftLabel{Cut: \ \ \strut}
    \BinaryInfC{$\Gamma,\Sigma\vdash\Delta,\Pi\strut$}\DisplayProof \\[15pt]  
\end{tabular}   


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The Axiom label disappeared here. But it works for me, also with a \strut after Cut: \ \

Comment: @Sapiens Sorry.  User "cut and paste" error.